# Modifying an XML document with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to modify the content of an XML file:

```
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
  <Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png"/>
...
</Types>
```

I need add `Default` children to `Types` as follows:

```
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
  <Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png"/>
  <Default Extension="jpg" ContentType="image/jpeg"/>
...
</Types>
```

I tried:

```
child_node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "Default", @doc
@doc.xpath('//Types/Default').first.add_next_sibling(child_node)


 #but @doc.xpath('//Types/Default').first #=> nil
```

How can I add a child node to `Types`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an XPath query against XML with a default namespace has been asked many times here in StackOverflow. In fact, I just posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33161230/2998271) to a C# question on the same topic a couple hours ago.

I don't know Ruby in particular, but commonly, to select an element in a default namespace using XPath, you need to map a prefix to the default namespace URI and use that prefix in your XPath, something like:

```
child_node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "Default", @doc
result = @doc.xpath('/d:Types/d:Default', 'd' => 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types').first
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,  it worked! <br/>
result = @doc.xpath('/d:Types/d:Default', 'd' => 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types').first

Comment: It's not necessary to thank us for edits. We do it because it improves the site.

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy to modify nodes using Nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
</Types>
EOT

types = doc.at('Types')
types.children = '<Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png"/><Default Extension="jpg" ContentType="image/jpeg"/>'

puts doc.to_xml

# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
# >>   <Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png"/>
# >>   <Default Extension="jpg" ContentType="image/jpeg"/>
# >> </Types>
```

Another way could be:

```
types = doc.at('Types')
[
  '<Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png"/>',
  '<Default Extension="jpg" ContentType="image/jpeg"/>'
].each do |node|
  types.add_child(Nokogiri::XML::Node.new(node, doc))
end

puts doc.to_xml

# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
# >> <<Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png"/>/><<Default Extension="jpg" ContentType="image/jpeg"/>/></Types>
```

Note that Nokogiri is happy to coerce a tag in string form into a node and add it. That can make life a lot easier if you're dealing with boilerplate you want to insert.